# Multiple C pointers

Tags: c, pointers, segmentation-fault

I've made a test, and I tried to pass a number to an int pointer like this:

```
void   mega_pointer(int *********number)
{
    *********number = 1337;
}
```

But I have a segmentation fault. I don't understand. Can somebody help me ?

EDIT : I add my main :

```
int   main(void)
{
   int ********number;

   mega_pointer(&number);
   printf("Result = %d\n", ********number);
   return 0;
}
```

PS : Sorry for your eye, I will never use 9* in a real program, it's just an experiment ^^

Comment: How do you call this function?

Comment: For simplicity sake, a pointer should point to a valid memory location before getting dereferenced. Check in your case if `number` is pointing to valid memory location. BTW, so many stars burnt my eyes.

Comment: Wow, that level of indirection would only exist in hell :)

Comment: @MiklósHomolya christmassy function ? somehow it reminds me of that part of the year.

Comment: Double pointers are enough in C++. How one could able to create that scenario...

Comment: Answered a question with triple pointer just today...

Comment: But I am thinking of triple of triple of triple pointer in C++ as this question has :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't have as many * characters in front of the assignment as you do in front of the parameter. It should be:

```
void mega_pointer(int *********number)
{
    *********number = 1337;
}
```

In the case that you have the right number of those in the program, it should work fine. You just have to make sure you have valid variables which you are pointing to. For example this program works:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void mega_pointer(int *********number)
{
    printf("%d\n", *********number);
    *********number = 1337;
    printf("%d\n", *********number);
}

int main()
{
    int blah = 1;
    int *blah1 = &blah;
    int **blah2 = &blah1;
    int ***blah3 = &blah2;
    int ****blah4 = &blah3;
    int *****blah5 = &blah4;
    int ******blah6 = &blah5;
    int *******blah7 = &blah6;
    int ********blah8 = &blah7;
    int *********blah9 = &blah8;

    mega_pointer(blah9);

    return 0;
}
```

It prints:

```
1
1337
```

As expected.

Comment: i think number points to a pointer to a pointer to a pointer to a pointer to a pointer to a pointer to a pointer to a pointer to an int.

Comment: Sorry, I forget a * here, but the number of * is right in my program  (otherwise it would not compile I think)

Answer (score 5):

The important question is how do you call the function; it needs a 9 indirection chain to be called successfully. See the example

```
#include <stdio.h>

void mega_pointer(int *********number)
{
    *********number = 1337;
}

int main() {
    int i = 42;
    int *p1 = &i;
    int **p2 = &p1;
    int ***p3 = &p2;
    int ****p4 = &p3;
    int *****p5 = &p4;
    int ******p6 = &p5;
    int *******p7 = &p6;
    int ********p8 = &p7;
    int *********p9 = &p8;
    mega_pointer(p9);
    printf("%d\n", i);
}
```

prints `1337`

Furthermore there is error in your program, as indeed your code is wrong, and you are assigning 1337 to an lvalue of type `int *` (in my code this would be `p1` instead of `i`; this however goes unnoticed if warnings are not enabled. If you compile your original code with `gcc -Wall`, then you get `warning: assignment makes pointer from integer without a cast [enabled by default]`.

Answer (score 1):

Your code works, but you have to set-up the pointers correctly first:

```
#include <stdio.h>

static void mega_pointer(int *********number)
{
    *********number = 1337;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    int a = 0;
    int *p1, **p2, ***p3, ****p4, *****p5, ******p6, *******p7, ********p8, *********p9;

    p1 = &a;
    p2 = &p1;
    p3 = &p2;
    p4 = &p3;
    p5 = &p4;
    p6 = &p5;
    p7 = &p6;
    p8 = &p7;
    p9 = &p8;

    mega_pointer(p9);

    printf("a=%d\n", a);
    return 0;
}
```

When run:

```
$ clang -o p ptest.c
$ ./p
a=1337
```

Answer (score 0):

the number op "*" sign represent the number of pointing that the variable is - meaning it's a pointer to a pointer to a pointer....

you have 9 "*" in the function signature, but "only" 8 in the `********number = 1337;`

if you'll do

```
void   mega_pointer(int *********number)
{
    *********number = 1337;
}
```

it'll work, but i would advise not to use that many pointing as it can be tricky (as you found out) and lead to truble

Answer (score 0):

Segmentation fault? Segmentation fault is something happen when you try to access memory which is not associated with it, or may doesn't exist for program.

you can create this fault just by:

```
int *ptr = NULL;
*ptr = 1;
```

You are accessing a memory which is not associated to this program for now or may be in past.